# TreeView_NodeMouseClick handler

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

How to make node being selected by right mouse button down ? 
I made it by right mouse button clicked like this:

```
private void myTreeView_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e) 
        {
            if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                this.myTreeView.SelectedNode = e.Node;
            }
        }
```

I want node being selected not by click, but just button down.

Comment: Are you saying you want the left button to **not** select the tree node?

Comment: I'm saying that I want to select nodes when I press the right button, but not released it. Click - it's when you press and release all the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you are looking for something like this:

```
void myTreeView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) {
    TreeNode tn = myTreeView.GetNodeAt(e.Location);
    if (tn != null) {
      myTreeView.SelectedNode = tn;
    }
  }
}
```

Subscribe to the MouseDown event of the TreeView and comment out the NodeMouseClick code.